# Beginner C++ Graphics (moving past the console)?

Tags: c++, graphics, console, game-engine

I have been using console for a while now. I would like to move on past the words_on_the_screen. 
I read about visual C++, I read about graphic engines .. I am confused on this topic .. I know not where to go next but I do want to learn graphic programming....

Comment: Sorry, your question is too broad for this community. There is a [List of game engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) on Wikipedia. May be, you have a look onto [SDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer) which I've never used myself but read some Q/As about it here. For graphics programming in general, I would recommend [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) which I use personally in professional work and just for fun to learn (by solving SO questions).

Comment: Concerning _too broad for this community_: Please, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). Just a friendly advice, SO is a programming blog meant to be used to ask specific questions and only when you cannot find the answer elsewhere. Broad and opinion-based questions should be avoided. It'll take you some time to get used to it - just look at other people's posts as examples. :-)

Anyway, the most commonly used library for Graphics is [OpenGL](http://openglbook.com/chapter-0-preface-what-is-opengl.html). You can look into [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) which a much simpler library, but soon enough you'll end up using OpenGL for your stuff.

If I where you, I'd start by looking at some [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) examples because it's easier to understand and it's a lot more C++ friendly than Modern OpenGL. NeHe has some nice tutorials [here](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~buffa/cours/synthese_image/DOCS/Tutoriaux/Nehe/opengl.htm).

To get you started with Modern OpenGL, I'd recommend you look at the following links:

- https://learnopengl.com/
- http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/
- http://openglbook.com/
- [Introduction to Modern OpenGL - Jon Macey, National Centre for Computer Animation](https://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/OpenGL/lecture1/slides.html?home=/jmacey/ASE#/)
- http://www.libsdl.org/
- http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/

I'd also get the [OpenGL SuperBible](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-Superbible-Comprehensive-Tutorial-Reference-ebook/dp/B01248FA0U/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1537355423&sr=8-1-fkmr1&keywords=OpenGL%20SuperBible%2C%20Seventh%20Edition), Seventh edition which is a complete tutorial and reference guide for the latest OpenGL version. You can also get the [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) Cookbook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-Shading-Language-Cookbook-Second/dp/1782167021/ref=dp_ob_title_bk), Second Edition which is a helpful guide for GLSL.

Hopefully the above will be enough to get you started.